# C++, count_if, and equals

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, countif

I have a `struct` with a name and number:

```
struct S {
  string name;
  int number;
};
```

Objects of `S` are stored in a vector. The vector is sorted based on `name`. There may be more than 1 item with the same `name`.

When iterating over the items in the vector, I'm trying to use `count_if` to detect duplicates:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
  const S& s = v[i];
  int count = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), XXX);
  // do something with count
}
```

In the above, I can't figure out what XXX should be. I tried to create a predicate, but its pretty useless since there's nothing to compare:

```
bool IsEqualName(const S& s) {
  return s.name == ???;
}
```

The documentation I'm finding [leaves a lot to be desired](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/).

I feel like I am missing something very obvious, but I don't see what it is. Could anyone point out my mistake?

Jeff

Comment: Are you trying to detect duplicates (yes/no), count duplicates, or remove duplicates?

Comment: @Cong Xu - For useful diagnostics, I think I would like the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your items are sorted, you can do better than find_if. In this case, `std::upper_bound` should work nicely.

Since you're basing the order of your `S` on `name` it's probably easiest to start by overloading `operator<` to do that:

```
struct S { 
    string name;
    int number;

    bool operator<(S const &other) { return name < other.name; }
};
```

[By the way, you can use that when sorting, as in `sort(v.begin(), v.end());` ]

To find how many times each item occurs, start from v.begin(), and use `std::upper_bound` to find the upper bound of items equal to the first, then update the beginning of the range you're looking at to the iterator `upper_bound` just returned, and repeat until you reach the end of the collection:

```
std::vector<size_t> counts;

auto pos = v.begin();

for (auto prev=v.begin(); prev != v.end(); prev = pos) {
    pos = std::upper_bound(prev, v.end(), *prev);
    counts.push_back(pos - prev);
}
```

This has at least the potential to be somewhat faster if you have quite a few duplicates -- or a lot faster if you really have a lot of duplicates (`upper_bound` is logarithmic, where `find_if` is linear).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I used something similar  (`count_adjacent`, I think).

Answer (score 5):

Could write a functor to achieve this:

```
struct FindName
{
  FindName(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
  bool operator()(const S& s) { return s.name == name_; }

private:
  std::string name_;
};


int count = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), FindName("noloader"));
```

Or use lambda if you are with C++11:

```
int count = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                     [](const S& s){ return s.name == "noloader"; });
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance billz - do I really need another class or struct to simply count equal items (for my definition of equal)?

Comment: because third parameter of cound_if is UnaryPredicate